# jQuery bind multiple .keydown events to one case

Tags: jquery, key-bindings

Since i'm pretty new to js and jquery i was wondering if it's possible to bind more than one key to an event. I tried `||`, `,`and `or` without any luck.

I'd like to bind `a` and `left-arrow` in an single case instead of making another case.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case (37 or 65):
            alert("left");
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:        
        case 65:
            alert("left");
            break;
    }
});
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn8kY/

Answer (score 0):

Simply list the `case`s you need grouped one below the other without a `break` in between.

```
switch(event.keyCode){
    case 37:
    case 65:
        alert("left");
        break;
}
```